# MySQL regular expression to exclude a certain literal at the beginning of a string?

Tags: mysql, regex

I'd like to match all "X joined your network" strings, X being any arbitrary string except when starting with "RE:". So I'd like to exclude "RE: X joined your network" type of strings.

I tried

```
^[^R][^E][^.:.].+ joined your network$
```

and

```
^[^.RE:.].+ joined your network$
```

and

```
^[^(RE\\:)].+ joined your network$
```

but none of these seem to be correct (using MySQL 5.1 with latin1 charset). What is the correct expression for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 
    table.field NOT LIKE "RE:%" AND table.field LIKE "%joined your network"
```

MySQL is not case sensitive so you'll catch RE: Re: and re:

Comment: +1 I agree no need for regular expressions in this case: http://sqlize.com/LdW8b8MsXc

Comment: Wow, is there no way to squeeze that into a single expression?

Comment: @mellamokb Thanks for introducing me to sqlize.com!

Comment: No, there would be no way in one expression. Mysql regular expressions don't support assertions. Although if you really want it http://www.mysqludf.org/lib_mysqludf_preg/

Answer (score 0):

The below query will help you to retrieve all your results from the table.

Here, I'm using **REGEXP** expression in the query for matching the pattern.

As we know that MySQL is case insensitive, so **RE** is the same as **re**.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
WHERE column_name NOT REGEXP '^[RE]' 
AND 
column_name REGEXP '(joined your network)$';
```